# Looking for algorithm (with low memory footprint): Toggling lights

Tags: algorithm, optimization, toggle

I'm having trouble figuring out this problem: imagine we have M lights. At first they are all off. A person does N moves. A move is when the person toggles all lights from a to b (inclusive). The question is: how many light bulbs will be on after those moves. The restrictions are:

- 1<=M<=1000000000
- 0<=N<=100000
- 1<=a<=b<=M
- Time limit: 1s, memory limit: 16MB.

Here is an example input:

```
12 3
2 6
2 6
1 3
```

This means that there are 12 ligt bulbs, the person did 3 moves. On his first move he toggled lights 2 through 6 (so now we have 2,3,4,5 and 6 on). On his second move he toggled the lights 2 through 6 again (so now all of them are off again). On his final move he toggled ligts 1 through 3 (lights 1,2 and 3 are on). So the answer would be 3 because only 3 ligts are on after this sequence of moves.

I need a little help with the idea of how I should solve this. Plainly creating a boolean array and switching it will not work because of how large the numbers can get.

Comment: Awfully looks like a [code jam](https://code.google.com/codejam/) excercise.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you don't need a dynamic data structures (where you have successive updates/queries), I would use the sweep technique to solve this, using a simple logic:

1) Sort all segment ends (In your example, it will result in [1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 6])

2) Scan the list, maintaining a "parity" variable. Whenever you encounter a new end, switch the parity. The scanning only visits the ends, so any step of the scan "sees" a segment with bulbs in the same state (either turned on or off, depending on the parity variable).

Pseudocode:

```
countTurnedOn(L : Array of Segment objects) {
  E = create empty list
  for (all s in L) {
    E.add(s.begin)
    E.add(s.end+1)
  }

  sort(E)

  count = 0
  parity = 0
  pos = 0
  for (i in 0 .. E.length-1) {
    newpos = E[i]
    count = count + (newpos - pos) * parity
    parity = (parity + 1) % 2
    pos = newpos
  }

  return count
}
```

Comment: What does the variable 's' mean?

Comment: @user3126750: It's the loop variable iterating over all segments in L.

Answer (score 1):

The problem wants you to compress the information about the light bulbs being on or off. - Instead of having an element in an array (or even single bit) dedicated to a single light bulb you have to focus on strings of lights being on or off.

A `LightString` will contain the following information:

- The `length` of the string (number of bulbs as long integer)
- The `state` of the bulbs (*on* or *off* represented by 1/0 or a boolean)

You can hold the series of strings in a dynamic container, I recommend a tree, because you will do lots of insertions (and probably a few deletions). You start out with a single string `{length:M, state:false}`.

When you handle a move you have two identical steps. For the first number (`a`):

- You find the string containing bulb `a`
- You split that string into two parts (insert a new one after the current one and adjust the lengths)
- You invert (negate) the state of every string beginning with the newly created one (the second part of the splitted one).

For `b` you do just the same.

You example (the first step):

- starting out `[{length:12, state:false}]`
- splitting at 2 `[{length:1, state:false},{length:11, state:false}]`
- inverting states starting with the new item `[{length:1, state:false},{length:11, state:true}]`
- splitting at 6 `[{length:1, state:false},{length:5, state:true},{length:6, state:true}]`
- inverting states starting with the new item `[{length:1, state:false},{length:5, state:true},{length:6, state:false}]`

After doing a step you might want to do a little cleanup, to keep memory usage and access time low: merging consecutive strings which have the same state. Deleting zero-length strings.